# error: Response not successful: Received status code 400" Graphql

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

what i wanted to do is to separate my schema from the index.js file. so here are the index.js file and schema.js file after separation.

//schema.js

```
import { gql, makeExecutableSchema } from 'apollo-server-express';

const typeDefs = gql`
    type Query {
        hello : String
    }
`;

const resolvers = {
    Query:{
        hello: () => 'HelloWorld!'
    }
};

export default makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
});
```

//index.js

```
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import express from 'express';

const schema = require('./schema');

const app = express();

const server = new ApolloServer({schema});
server.applyMiddleware({app});

app.listen(4000, ()=> {
    console.log(`app is working on port 4000 ${server.graphqlPath}`);
});
```

i still can open graphql playground on localhost:4000/graphql
but after the separation i receive the following error.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced the line `const schema = require('./schema');` to `import schema from './schema';` solved my problem.
even though I am using node V8.10 I used the babel compiler to use modern syntax with node. the old syntax was the issue.